# How to use Qualys API v2 with PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use the Qualys API v2 to get an xml host list returned. I think you must use cURL, but I am unfamiliar with it. Here is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/asset/host/?action=list&details=Basic");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Requested-With: Manitowoc Service Account'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close();
$hostobj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Comment: What is the question?  Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, curl is not required for QualysGuard API calls. As long as you can make https calls you can use any method you would like. But curl is a nice framework because everything is already implemented (with perl, another alternative would be LWP).

I have not been able to find the issue with your code, but I posted a perl script that launches and downloads a Qualys report by making API requests "using WWW::Curl::Easy": https://community.qualys.com/docs/DOC-3222

I hope it could help you to write your own perl API request with libcurl.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with your code, but of course we can't see what values you are using for the username and password, and whether those credentials actually exist in QualysGuard.

To get status/error information from curl for a given request, use `curl_getinfo()`, `curl_error()`, and `curl_errno()` as described [in the cURL Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).